# Google Cloud Text-to-Speech API - permission error

Tags: google-cloud-platform, text-to-speech, google-cloud-speech

I am attempting to set up Google Cloud Text-to-Speech API following these instructions - https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/docs/quickstart
I have successfully followed steps 1-6 for setting up Google SDK and authenticating with service account credentials.
However, when I attempt to run the sample HTTP request for synthesising speech I receive the following error:

> Cloud Text-to-Speech API has not been used in project usable-auth-library before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/texttospeech.googleapis.com/overview?project=usable-auth-library then retry.

When following the link in the error message it leads to the following page:

> The API "texttospeech.googleapis.com" doesn't exist or you don't have permission to access it.

I am grateful for help.

Comment: It looks like your code is trying to authenticate using the `usable-auth-library` project instead of your *actual* project. My guess is that's due to how the credentials are being used. Have you tried setting the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` environment variable to the location of your service account JSON file instead?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have set GOOGLE_APPLICATIONS_CREDENTIALS as you suggest but still get the same error. Does the gcloud command in the curl request (curl -H "Authorization: Bearer "$(gcloud auth application-default print-access-token)) need to be changed perhaps?

Comment: Possibly - if you take the `application-default` out of there, does that help? If you were planning on using a client library, it might be worth skipping straight to that, as that may make it easier to make sure you're really using the service account credentials.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. This has been resolved now, by rerunning the gcloud auth activate-service-account step after setting the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable.

Comment: to confirm I did also take out 'application-default' as suggested

Comment: @DaisyShipton Could you please post your comment as an answer?

Comment: @komarkovich: It sounds like there was more to it than that; I suspect the OP is in a better position to add an answer.

Comment: Where exactly is `application-default` @MKB

Comment: Hi I'm afraid I don't know where application-default is - I just followed the suggestion from @DaisyShipton to remove the reference to it. Sorry not to be more helpful, I am very new to developing and to stackoverflow.

Answer (score 4):

I easier to integrate in most plarforms using the API key instead of the service account key that Google recomends on their docs.

These are all the steps you need to get to the the API key

1. Create a project (or use an existing one) in the [Cloud
   Console](https://console.cloud.google.com/).
2. Make sure that [billing](https://console.cloud.google.com/billing?project=_) is enabled for your project.
3. Enable the [Text-to-Speech API](https://console.cloud.google.com/flows/enableapi?apiid=texttospeech.googleapis.com).
4. Create an [API key](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials?project=_).

You'll probably only need the last step (if you followed all the steps correctly like you said).

And then you can use the curl command like so

```
Curl -H "X-Goog-Api-Key: PUT_YOUR_API_KEY_HERE" \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8" \
  --data "{
    'input':{
      'text':'Android is a mobile operating system developed by Google,
         based on the Linux kernel and designed primarily for
         touchscreen mobile devices such as smartphones and tablets.'
    },
    'voice':{
      'languageCode':'en-gb',
      'name':'en-GB-Standard-A',
      'ssmlGender':'FEMALE'
    },
    'audioConfig':{
      'audioEncoding':'MP3'
    }
  }" "https://texttospeech.googleapis.com/v1beta1/text:synthesize" > synthesize-text.txt
```

Comment: This fixed the issue for me.

Comment: can we use client library of PHP while using this step.

Answer (score 1):

In case this helps anyone, I ran into this error after adding the API through the Google console to an existing Google Service Account with JWT credentials.

I followed the link to the Quickstart Protocol and was able to get it working On the page below, I clicked on `Enable the API`.

https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/docs/quickstart-protocol

[image: Text-to-Speech Quickstart]

On the next page, I clicked the `Create a project` drop down and selected an existing project. There was no need to get new credentials.

[image]

I'm using Go and was then able to run my code using `golang.org/x/oauth2/google`.

Answer (score 0):

Once you created an API key, here is your curl one-liner that fetches the result, parses it, formats it and decodes it.

1. Generate API key here https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials?showWizardSurvey=true
2. Install [jq](https://linuxhint.com/bash_jq_command/) JSON parser
3. Run:

```
curl -H "X-Goog-Api-Key: APIKEYHERE" -H "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8" --data "{ 'input':{ 'text':'I\'ve added the event to your calendar.' }, 'voice':{ 'languageCode':'en-gb', 'name':'en-GB-Standard-A', 'ssmlGender':'FEMALE' }, 'audioConfig':{ 'audioEncoding':'MP3' } }" "https://texttospeech.googleapis.com/v1/text:synthesize" | jq '.audioContent' | cut -d "\"" -f 2 > encodedOutput && base64 --decode encodedOutput > texttospeech.mp3
```